# Quantity on cart can be only set to 1

Tags: 8, commerce

I can add to the cart as many items as like, for example 4. When I visit the cart page, I can see 4 items in the cart.
However, I cannot proceed to the checkout as I see a message which says the value should not be greater than 1. When I inspect the quantity form element, I can see the minimum and the maximum are set to 1.

I also cannot remove items from cart unless I change the quantity to 1.

Where can I find the settings for that?

I inspected all the commerce configuration values and the settings for the commerce_cart_form view, but I didn't find anything that could help.

I also have the *Commerce Simple Stock* module enabled. Maybe it interferes somehow with the quantity value.

Comment: Could it be that there's only one of the product in stock?

Comment: No, there is more. As I wrote I can add to cart as many as I want and I can see the valid quantity in a cart, just the input/quantity in cart view seems to be set up to not take values greater than 1